# When is a ConsumerRecord "consumed"

Tags: apache-kafka

I am reading Kafka: The Definitive Guide, and there is a section that states that poll with auto commit enabled will commit the offsets returned in the last poll. I was curious about the nitty gritty and wanted to verify that it was the last poll versus the current poll, so began digging around. It seems that offset commits are based off of whether the `ConsumerRecord` was consumed, and digging into the code keeps going deeper to Interceptors and whatnot. However I still don't have a clear answer of whether it is the current poll that is about to return that is committed or the last one? And now I'm curious about this consumed aspect. If I never iterate the `ConsumerRecords` returned by poll, will they still be marked as consumed and therefore auto committed?

Answer (score 0):

As is sometimes the case after digging and then writing up a question I believe I realized and then verified the answer myself. Per [this KafkaConsumer code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java#L1125) the current batch is auto marked as consumed when it is passed out of `poll`:

```
return this.interceptors.onConsume(new ConsumerRecords<>(records));
```

And the auto commit is done before this, so it is indeed the last poll which is committed.